# C++ : using prime number and not a prime number

Tags: c++

I need to write  a program in C++ that receives a positive number greater than 2 from the user, and prints whether the number is prime or not.

Reminder: A number is prime if it is divisible by a remainder only in itself and in 1, and not in any other number. Therefore, primary 2 is divisible only by itself and 1, but non-primary 4 is also divisible by 2.

but the probleme is in the loop, He repeats the steps

and I have a problem with the number 2177 which is not a prime number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int nNumber;
    int i;
    cout << "Enter a number:" << endl;
    cin >> nNumber;

    if (nNumber >= 2)
    {
        for (i = 2; i <= sqrt (nNumber); i++)
        {
            if (nNumber % i == 0)
            {
                // he is repete the step her 
                cout << nNumber << " is not a prime number." << endl;
            }

        }
        if (nNumber % i != 0)
        {
            cout << nNumber << " is a prime number. " << endl;

        }


    }

    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: Your title is unclear. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help].

Comment: Since you never change the value of `nNumber` the loop is infinite. I think you should've accept user input inside of the loop.

Comment: This is probably a good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @VTT What?  nNumber is the limit, i is the counter, and he *does* change i.

Comment: You need to remember that you have printed "is not prime", and not print "is prime" if you have.  You should also exit the loop as soon as you know the value is not prime.

Comment: `void main()` is incorrect, as `main()` should return an `int`, `using namespace std;` is frowned upon because of namespace pollution and furthermore, what is `system("pause")` supposed to do?

Comment: why so many downvotes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just define a Boolean variable and set its value to 'true'. You only need to run a loop "n/2 times" as the maximum divisor is half of the actual number. So, if the input number is divisible by any value between '2-n/2', set the value of Boolean variable false. In the end, print the result on the basis of Boolean variable value.
Have a look at this link!

https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/examples/prime-number

Comment: Link only answers are not very helpful if the link rots.  Please summarize the information in the link.

Comment: Please [learn how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The maximum divisor is sqrt(n), not n/2.  For large numbers there is a *big* difference.

Answer (score 3):

You do not describe what problem you have, but what I get when I run this program is:

```
2177 is not a prime number.
2177 is a prime number. 
sh: 1: pause: not found
```

First your applications finds correctly that 2177 is not prime (at `i=3`), but then you continue your loop (which is not necessary or useful because it will just print the line again if it finds extra values).

However your main problem is that you always execute the line `if (nNumber % i != 0)`, even if a value has been found. At this point `i` has the fixed value `((int)sqrt(2177)) + 1` (which is 47) because the loop is completed at that point and will stay at that value. Because 2177 is not divisible by 47 you print out the message `2177 is a prime number.`.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work. Added **break** statement -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int nNumber;
    int i;

    cout << "Enter a number:" << endl;
    cin >> nNumber;

    if (nNumber >= 2)
    {
        for (i = 2; i <= sqrt (nNumber); i++)
        {
            if (nNumber % i == 0)
            {
                cout << nNumber << " is not a prime number." << endl;
                break;
            }

        }

        if (nNumber % i != 0)
        {
            cout << nNumber << " is a prime number. " << endl;
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```